# Ansible wait_for module, start at end of file

Tags: ansible

With the `wait_for`module in Ansible if I use `search_regex='foo'` on a file

it seems to start at the beginning of the file, which means it will match on old data, thus when restarting a process/app (Java) which appends to a file rather than start a new file, the `wait_for` module will exit true for old data, but I would like to check from the tail of the file.

Comment: I am not sure `wait_for` can support `tail` of a file.. You may want to try some other way to check if the process/app is up or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regular expression in `search_regex` of `wait_for` module is by default set to multiline.

You can register the contents of the last line and then search for the string appearing after that line (this assumes there are no duplicate lines in the log file, i.e. each one contains a time stamp):

```
vars:
  log_file_to_check: <path_to_log_file>
  wanted_pattern: <pattern_to_match>

tasks:
  - name: Get the contents of the last line in {{ log_file_to_check }}
    shell: tail -n 1 {{ log_file_to_check }}
    register: tail_output

  - name: Create a variable with a meaningful name, just for clarity
    set_fact:
      last_line_of_the_log_file: "{{ tail_output.stdout }}"

  ### do some other tasks ###

  - name: Match "{{ wanted_pattern }}" appearing after "{{ last_line_of_the_log_file }}" in {{ log_file_to_check }}
    wait_for:
      path: "{{ log_file_to_check }}"
      search_regex: "{{ last_line_of_the_log_file }}\r(.*\r)*.*{{ wanted_pattern }}"
```

Comment: Going to take this as the answer thank you, helloV's answer is also correct, as the wait_for module cannot do the task on its own, but this is the answer to the question I asked.

Comment: Thanks. That works great. However I've had problem with my log files ... and took me some time why it is not working for me ...
So just to make sure that {{ last_line_of_the_log_file }} doesn't have special regex characters
In my case the search string looks like this:
**search_regex: "{{ last_line_of_the_log_file | replace('[','.')|replace(']','.')|replace('(','.')|replace(')','.') }}\r(.*\r)*.*Initialization completed in .* seconds"**
Maybe that would be useful for someone that would stack in the same place :)

Comment: I used the following:
`{{ tail_output.stdout | regex_escape() }}\r(.*\r)*.*{{ wanted_pattern }}"`

[Ansible regex_escape()](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/regex_escape_filter.html)

Answer (score 5):

[techraf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41209087/4895024) would work if every line inside the log file is time stamped. Otherwise, the log file may have multiple lines that are identical to the last one.

A more robust/durable approach would be to check how many lines the log file currently has, and then search for the regex/pattern occurring after the 'nth' line.

```
vars:
  log_file: <path_to_log_file>
  pattern_to_match: <pattern_to_match>

tasks:
  - name: "Get contents of log file: {{ log_file }}"
    command: "cat {{ log_file }}"
    changed_when: false  # Do not show that state was "changed" since we are simply reading the file!
    register: cat_output

  - name: "Create variable to store line count (for clarity)"
    set_fact:
      line_count: "{{ cat_output.stdout_lines | length }}"

##### DO SOME OTHER TASKS (LIKE DEPLOYING APP) #####

  - name: "Wait until '{{ pattern_to_match}}' is found inside log file: {{ log_file }}"
    wait_for:
      path: "{{ log_file }}"
      search_regex: "^{{ pattern_to_skip_preexisting_lines }}{{ pattern_to_match }}$"
      state: present
    vars:
      pattern_to_skip_preexisting_lines : "(.*\\n){% raw %}{{% endraw %}{{ line_count }},{% raw %}}{% endraw %}"  # i.e. if line_count=100, then this would equal "(.*\\n){100,}"
```

Answer (score 2):

One more method, using intermediate temp file for tailing new records:

```
- name: Create tempfile for log tailing
  tempfile:
    state: file
  register: tempfile
- name: Asynchronous tail log to temp file 
  shell: tail -n 0 -f /path/to/logfile > {{ tempfile.path }}
  async: 60
  poll: 0
- name: Wait for regex in log
  wait_for:
    path: "{{ tempfile.path }}"
    search_regex: 'some regex here'
- name: Remove tempfile
  file:
    path: "{{ tempfile.path }}"
    state: absent
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you can force a log rotation on your java app log file then straightforward wait_for will achieve what you want since there won't be any historical log lines to match

I am using this approach with rolling upgrade of mongodb and waiting for "waiting for connections" in the mongod logs before proceeding.

sample tasks:

```
tasks:
  - name: Rotate mongod logs
    shell: kill -SIGUSR1 $(pidof mongod)
    args:
      executable: /bin/bash

  - name: Wait for mongod being ready
    wait_for:
      path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
      search_regex: 'waiting for connections'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with @Slezhuk's answer above. But I found an issue. The tail command won't stop after the completion of the playbook. It will run forever. I had to add some more logic to stop the process:

```
# the playbook doesn't stop the async job automatically. Need to stop it
- name: get the PID async tail
  shell: ps -ef | grep {{ tmpfile.path }} | grep tail | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
  register: pid_grep
- set_fact:
    tail_pid: "{{pid_grep.stdout}}"
# the tail command shell has two processes. So need to kill both
- name: killing async tail command
  shell: ps -ef | grep " {{tail_pid}} " | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -15
- name: Wait the tail process to be killed
  wait_for:
    path: /proc/{{tail_pid}}/status
    state: absent
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across this page when trying to do something similar and ansible has come a way since the above, so here's my solution using the above. Also used the timeout linux command with async - so doubling up a bit.

It would be much easier if the application rotated logs on startup - but some apps aren't nice like that!

As per this page..
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html

> The async tasks will run until they either complete, fail or timeout according to their async value.

Hope it helps someone

```
- name: set some common vars
  set_fact:
    tmp_tail_log_file: /some/path/tail_file.out # I did this as I didn't want to create a temp file every time, and i put it in the same spot.
    timeout_value: 300 # async will terminate the task - but to be double sure I used timeout linux command as well.
    log_file: /var/logs/my_log_file.log
    
  - name: "Asynchronous tail log to {{ tmp_tail_log_file }}"
    shell: timeout {{ timeout_value }} tail -n 0 -f {{ log_file }} > {{ tmp_tail_log_file }}
    async: "{{ timeout_value }}"
    poll: 0

  - name: "Wait for xxxxx to finish starting"
    wait_for:
      timeout: "{{ timeout_value }}"
      path: "{{ tmp_tail_log_file }}"
      search_regex: "{{ pattern_search }}"
    vars:
      pattern_search: (.*Startup process completed.*)
    register: waitfor

  - name: "Display log file entry"
    debug:
      msg: 
        - "xxxxxx startup completed - the following line was matched in the logs"
        - "{{ waitfor['match_groups'][0] }}"
```