# Ansible : wait_for with two regex

Tags: ansible

Using [this - solved - question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41204313/ansible-wait-for-module-start-at-end-of-file) concerning a regex search with "wait_for" and "regex_search" into a log file, I ask if it's possible to use the wait_for condition with a multiple regex.

I'm using with success the [Sami Badra's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50239630/10187254)  :

```
 vars:
  log_file: <path_to_log_file>
  pattern_to_match: <pattern_to_match>

 tasks:
   - name: "Get contents of log file: {{ log_file }}"
      command: "cat {{ log_file }}"
      changed_when: false  
      register: cat_output

    - name: "Create variable to store line count (for clarity)" 
      set_fact:
        line_count: "{{ cat_output.stdout_lines | length }}"  

     ##### DO SOME OTHER TASKS (LIKE DEPLOYING APP) ##### 

   - name: "Wait until '{{ pattern_to_match}}' is found inside log file: {{ log_file }}"
     wait_for:
       path: "{{ log_file }}"
       search_regex: "^{{ pattern_to_skip_preexisting_lines }}{{ pattern_to_match }}$"
         state: present
      vars:
          pattern_to_skip_preexisting_lines : "(.*\\n){% raw %}{{% endraw %}{{ line_count }},{% raw %}}{% endraw %}"  # i.e. if line_count=100, then this would equal "(.*\\n){100,}
```

to match a single regex (for example "ABCD System Started OK").

Now I'm trying to use the same wait_for to catch multiple regex, for example

- "ABCD System Started OK" when start is complete/correct
- "ABCD System Failed" when something goes wrong.

and, afterwards, use fail/debug to proceed or stop...but I fail in each test using an array of regex or with_items.

Is possible to check multiple regex at the same time on Ansible?

If yes, there's a better way or elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ansible 2.2.1.0 and 2.6.1 this works for me:

```
- name: wait for multiple regex
  become: yes
  wait_for:
    path: "{{ log_file }} "
    search_regex: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "ABCD System Started OK"
    - "ABCD System Failed"
```

Comment: Thanks Zach, it works but not (for me) with the previous code. Your example is expecting both regex are true to continue the playbook: 

`TASK [jstart : myserver01 - Wait until 'ABCD System Started OK' is found inside log file: /tmp/foo] ********************************************************** 
ok: [myserver01] => (item=ABCD System Started OK) 
ok: [myserver01] => (item=ABCD System Failed) `

and after that the playbook continue. I need something to break the task after one of two condition is true.